# Auto variable retains value across function calls

Tags: c

Look at the following code snippet:

```
void abc(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

void xyz(void)
{
    int a = 44;
}

int main(void)
{
    xyz();
    abc();
}
```

When I compile and run the program, it shows value of 44. I expected it to display some other garbage value. If I use optimization, the result is as expected. Can someone help me to understand the exact problem?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are using an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
void abc(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

You are using `a` uninitialized, which is **undefined behaviour**. This means anything could happen, including (but **not guaranteed to**) the memory allocated for `a` in `abc()` still holding some previous value (i.e. the one assigned during `xyz()`).

A different thread could have mangled that memory. It could have been zeroed-out when you returned from `xyz()`. The system could be running a type of RAM that "forgets" unused memory, replacing the previous value with random noise. **Do not ever touch undefined behaviour**.

It might be a bit less confusing if you rename one of the two variables to something else than `a`. That they have the same *name* has no impact here; they are the first `int` declared in the respective function, which -- *on your specific architecture* -- resulted in them occupying the same memory address. *This is a coincidence, not something the language guarantees*. I.e., it is *not defined* to happen.